# Make only the arrowheads larger in Gephi Overview Section?

Tags: gephi

I have a very dense network. In order to see the directionality of the arrow, I have to zoom in really deep. I cannot increase the width of the arrows too much since the graph becomes too cluttered. Is there some way I can increase just the arrowhead size without affecting its width?

I am aware of a setting in the Preview tab under the "Edge Arrows" section that lets me control this. But is there a way to do this setting in the Overview tab as well?

Thank you for your time.